# JavaEE6 Conversation.end doesn't reset conversation.id to 1

Tags: java-ee-6, conversation-scope

Is the conversation.id not reset when conversation.end is called?

Scenario: I have an app that uses conversation scope in CRUD, so when I visit the list page it starts a conversation. Go to the detail and click back will call end conversation and begin conversation again. But while I'm at debug mode I found out that when conversation.end() is called conversation is set to null. Then when I reinvoke conversation.begin() conversation.id is not reset to 1 but rather the last value + 1. Is it correct to behave that way?

What's more puzzling is after logout and login again, the conversation.id pick up the last value + 1.

My environment: Jboss 7.1.3 using javaee-api.

```
protected void beginConversation() {
    if (conversation.isTransient()) {
        conversation.begin();
    }
}

protected void endConversation() {
    if (!conversation.isTransient()) {
        conversation.end();
    }
}
```

So basically I have a base entity (where the above code is defined.) extended by all the backing beans. When a list page is render it will call beginConversation. Clicking the back button in detail page will call endConversation.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Hi @PetrMensik, I've added some code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should the conversation id be reset?

The best way to solve those questions is to directly having a look in the [specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/contexts.html#d0e5678) (in your case CDI 1.0), which states that the container has to generate an id for the conversation, but not how.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449601/what-causes-a-conversation-id-to-be-incremented) question, which states how it's done in WELD.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would reset when I start another conversation. It works properly I'm just curious why the id increment even on newly started conversation. I guess that's the way it is specified.